# Files.createSymbolicLink() takes an array of FileAttribute<?> as an argument; does it make sense on any OS?

Tags: java, unix, symlink, java.nio.file

[The prototype of `Files.createSymbolicLink()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) is:

```
static Path createSymbolicLink(Path link, Path target,
    FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
```

Well... Why?

A symlink is nothing else than an inode whose content is a string pointing to... Well, whatever. The target can even not be valid at all.

Out of curiosity, I tried this (yes, it runs as root, but this is on purpose here):

```
root@alustriel:/tmp# cat Test.java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public final class Test {
    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        final UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService =
                FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();

        final UserPrincipal user = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName("fge");

        final FileAttribute<UserPrincipal> attr =
                new FileAttribute<UserPrincipal>() {
            @Override
            public String name() {
                return "owner:owner";
            }

            @Override
            public UserPrincipal value() {
                return user;
            }
        };

        final Path target = Paths.get("whocares, I don't exist anyway");
        final Path symlink = Paths.get("/tmp/meh");

        Files.createSymbolicLink(symlink, target, attr);
    }
}
root@alustriel:/tmp# javac Test.java 
root@alustriel:/tmp# java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'owner:owner' not supported as initial attribute
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileModeAttribute.toUnixMode(UnixFileModeAttribute.java:74)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:440)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createSymbolicLink(Files.java:996)
    at Test.main(Test.java:41)
```

Well, I kind of expected that.

The only situation I know where a symlink's permissions matters is in Linux's /proc/*/fd/ since the permissions of the symlink match the permissions with which the file descriptor was opened. But this is a systems generated symlink and is nothing like what the user can generate.

Is there any OS where a symlink's permissions actuall affect the behavior of the symlink and/or its target in any way, shape or form?

---

edit: well, I *could* change the owner of a symlink with `chown` but... Again, what's the point?

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle docs say that this is just for future use:

> The FileAttributes vararg enables you to specify initial file attributes that are set atomically when the link is created. **However, this argument is intended for future use and is not currently implemented.** ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html); emphasis mine)

On a Mac, permissions [seem to be settable](https://superuser.com/questions/303040/how-do-file-permissions-apply-to-symlinks), though they don't seem to have much of an effect. I created a file readable only by root, and two symlinks to it: one world-readable, one readable only by root. I could `cat` the file using all three, but `ls -l` only listed the link target for the world-readable link when I ran it as my user:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  wheel   7 Dec 21 21:32 actual
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  wheel   6 Dec 21 21:33 link_for_all -> actual
lrwx------ 1 root  wheel   6 Dec 21 21:34 link_for_root
```

I couldn't find any other differences in behavior, but it's *something*, so perhaps you'll be able to use `createSymbolicLink` to create such a symlink in the future.

Comment: Aah, so you can do that with Mac... With Linux, if you chmod a symlink it is gently ignored; "permissions" are always 777.